# Crystal Reports Incorrect Grand Total

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I tried looking for the answer but all the questions were more complicated, needing more complicated answers.

I'm trying to find the sum of a column in Crystal Reports, putting it into the footer, but when I do it gets a grand total that is totally incorrect. For example, i want to find the sum of the column balance, which has only got one row with £0.68, but CR puts £69.36. I have had to suppress the duplicates, so that probably has something to do with it, but since i'm new to everything code related I need some help.

Comment: One Tip:  Suppressing things doesn't prevent them from being processed.  It just stops them from printing.  This means they still get counted and summed in summary fields.

Are you using Summary Fields or Running Total Fields?  How are you grouping data in your report design?  It would also help if you could describe the layout of your report such as what sections are available.

Comment: A description of your data set from your database may also be helpful.  :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I don't really understand why it always makes duplicates, it seems more like a bug. I'm using summary fields, and I'm not really grouping the data, I'm using Select Expert to take all the data for a single customer. In terms of layout, I've got the Report and Page Header, the Details and the Report Footer so far. It's also only one page. I'm using a stored procedure to generate the report, joining three tables. They include information about the invoice, the Invoice Total, Payments, and the Balance. The Balance is formulated in the database to = Inv.Total - Paymen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate values you are seeing most likely are not a bug, but rather are data columns that have a many-to-one relationship with other data columns in a joined data table.  Which is when grouping your data becomes necessary.  For example, within a database one Invoice record typically joins with 1 or more Invoice Detail records.  Each Invoice Detail record will have the same Invoice Number, and you will have duplicate Invoice Number values in your report.  You say you begin by filtering your report to a single customer, but if that customer has more than one invoice, without a grouping level on Invoice Number, then the details section is the only place you can print the Invoice Number and it will duplicate over and over again for each item on the invoice that is defined on your Invoice Detail table.  By grouping on Invoice Number you can use the group header section to print data fields that have a 1-to-1 relationship with any one invoice without duplicating them.  Then you can use a summary field in the group footer section that properly reflects your grouped data without counting the duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble following. How would I use the group header section to print fields that have a 1-to-1 relationship?

Comment: Never mind, I've found a solution. Your answer helped a lot in understanding how it works, so thank you. Basically what I did, was insert two groups, the first being 'Company Name', and the other being 'Statement ID' (I made a new column). Then I created a running total, set the 'Field to Summarize' to 'Balance', set it to 'evaluate on change of group' (Statement ID - the second group) and set it to 'reset on change of group' (Customer Name - the first group). Then I put the running total in the footer of the first group.